# Always visible UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to place a `UIView` that will inform the user what is the status of the app. I want that view to be visible even if the user switches views, same thing as the `UINavigationBar` is always visible, but I don't want to use that bar, I would like to add another view that will show a message.

How can this be done? I can't add the `view` to the current `view`, because it will disappear, if the user changes views.
It should be added to the `window`? But how? I would then have to resize the views so that my new `view` can fit, but how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `appDelegate.m` add your view as subView of window.

```
UIView *mainBg = [[UIView alloc] init];
mainBg.frame = newframe;
[self.window addSubview:mainBg];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a container view controller and set it as the `rootViewController` of the apps window.

Inside this container you have your status view, and you also resize the windows real `rootViewController` to take up the remaining space as a subview. If you are using a standard container view conrtoller (tab, navigation etc) as the root then you can use standard navigation methods and the status view will always be visible

There would be problems if you wanted to present modal views though, since these would go over the top of the status view

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UINavigationController` you can add your view to its view.

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubView:yourView];
```

Presenting modal views would cover the view, as stated in the other answer.